# Is sqlite fast enough for it to replace pre-loading stuff into memory?

Tags: python, database, memory, sqlite

Say I have a game server which contains 50 players, each player has a list of characters (anything from five to five hundred characters, and a player can only play one character at a time).

Would it be better to store all the characters into a database, then when the player connects to the server, load all the characters from the database at once and store them into a list:

```
def on_connect(**event_args):
    player = Player()
    player.characters = load_characters(event_args['playerid'])  # Load everything at once
    players[event_args['playerid']] = player    

def on_character_change(**event_args):
    player = players[event_args['playerid']]
    for char in player.characters:
        if char.characterid == event_args['characterid']:
            player.current_character = char
            break
```

And then when the player disconnects from the server, save all of his characters into the datbase.

Or would it be better to only load one character at a time from the database, and then when the player changes character, save the current character into the database, discard it from the memory, and load the new character from the database?

So basically RAM vs database load speed, how good are databases (sqlite3) actually?
Let me know if you need any more info, not sure how to ask a question like this...

Comment: When your predicted scale is 50*500, everything is fast. Go with whatever is your first instinct, and if it seems slow, write a couple benchmarks to see which parts are slowing you down. That said, sqlite databases are very fast as long as just one application is attempting to access it at a given time.

Comment: "Is sqlite fast enough for it to replace pre-loading stuff into memory?" Since you cannot define what is "fast enough", you should avoid premature optimization, use what is most convenient, and see if in real use it is too slow. Echoing @elyase my feeling is that sqlite will not be a bottleneck (but I don't agree with changing the cache size). if you loaded the entire DB to core, how would you know what bits you needed to write back or would you just write back the entire DB? That would be inefficient. If you just loaded a single (real or virtual) row, you'd know exactly what needed writing.

Comment: I see you point but now try to see it the other way, if your argument were strictly valid then we would have to reduce the `cache_size`. I think this and may be even the `page_size` need to be tuned for each app/environment. The default value is a compromise chosen to work reasonably well in all platforms but from what I have seen in most cases it benefits from being bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 50 players I wouldn't worry about improving the speed of using plain Sqlite3, almost everything will be memory based. Sqlite3 caches the last 100 statements (you can increase this value if needed) and also 2000 pages of 1k size=2Mb (should be enough in your case). You can increase this value with:

```
conn.execute("""PRAGMA cache_size = 4000""")  # 4 Mb
```

See the [Optimization FAQ](http://web.utk.edu/~jplyon/sqlite/SQLite_optimization_FAQ.html#pragmas) for more details.